# Terraform plan showing error if prevent_destroy lifecycle is set

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Getting below error while running Terraform Plan or Terraform refresh, How to resolve this.

Error: Instance cannot be destroyed

on ..\ec2\ec2.tf line 89:
89: resource "aws_instance" "strdicomdev" {

Resource module.ec2.aws_instance.strdicomdev has lifecycle.prevent_destroy
set, but the plan calls for this resource to be destroyed. To avoid this error
and continue with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or reduce
the scope of the plan using the -target flag.

Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...

Comment: The error message exactly says what to do: "To avoid this error and continue with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or reduce the scope of the plan using the -target flag."

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message:

```
module.ec2.aws_instance.strdicomdev has lifecycle.prevent_destroy
```

If you look at this module it will have a lifecycle stanza which includes prevent_destroy = true. Since it's a module, maybe it is has a variable to control this, and the default is to prevent destroy. The easiest thing to do is to remove the prevent_destroy part of the lifecycle stanza or set it to false (either by changing the module or setting the variable if the module uses one)

Comment: actually its required to prevent EC2 instances from destroying.

Comment: Then what is your question? You are describing a working system

Comment: The question is - why does this happen on 'plan'? It should only happen on 'apply'

Comment: No it shouldn't, the plan stage checks the validity of the code, in this case it isn't valid and the plan is rejected